# How do you load a image via array index into UIImage from coreData

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3

I have searched all over the place and am unable to figure out how would you load one image to a `UIIMage` using array index from coredata.

I have tried this:

```
 imgDisplay.image = NSData["Image"][index]
```

but obviously I am getting errors as the above syntax is not correct.

Comment: You need to show more code for us to help you. To load an image from data you need to use `imgDisplay.image = UIImage(data: data)`

Comment: How are you fetching these Images? `NSData` is class and doesn't have subscript support.

Comment: Nathan Oliver just to inform you I am dyslexic. Will do my best not to use slang english words thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to creat an array of type NSManagedObject. You will fetch the data and append the fetched data to it.

```
var results = [NSManagedObject]()
```

Then, add the following method to perform the fetch request, call it from viewDidAppear() or wherever you want.

```
func loadData() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MY_ENTITY_NAME")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: true)]
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        results = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("Error in fetching reuqest error: \(err)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData() // if you are adding the fetched data to a table view. 
}
```

When you want to add a specific UIImage at indexPath to the UIImageView, call this:

```
    if (results[3] as! MY_ENTITY_NAME).image != nil {
        my_UIImageView.image = UIImage(data: (results[3] as! Task).image! as Data)
    }
```

The .image here is the attribute name. And the 3 is just a random indexPath, you could use indexPath.row